# How to print a file with comments in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, printing

I have a `.m` file with comments in it. When I try to print it, it prints only the code and not the comments. Are there alternate ways to print from within the MATLAB Editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on a mac (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux) from inside the MATLAB editor, it neatly prints out the entire file *including* the comments.

Here's a sample output from printing to a file.

[image]